# Assign 3 gameObjects to 3 random specified positions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 3 gameObjects created in my scene. And I have 3 Vector positions defined as well. I want to randomly assign each of these gameObjects to one of the positions. But no more than 1 gameObject should have same position as other. How do I use Random.Range() property here? Or is there a better approach?

```
public GameObject[] myObjs;
public Vector3[] myPos;

void Start(){
 var number = Random.Range (0, myPos.Length);
}
```

Comment: fisher-yates algorithm can help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply shuffle one of the arrays and then assign them in order like e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

public GameObject[] myObjs;
public Vector3[] myPos;

void Start()
{
    var randomPositions = myPos.OrderBy(n => Random.value).ToArray();

    var amount = Mathf.Min(myPos.Length, myObs.Length);

    for(var i = 0; i < amount; i++)
    {
        myObjs[i].transform.position = randomPositions[i];
    }
}
```

This simply uses [Linq `OrderBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby) to sort the items of `myPos` gien a certain order "property". Here we simply pass in [`Random.value`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Random-value.html). => `randomPositions` will contain all the item of `myPos` exactly once but in random order. So then you can just iterate and assign them in a normal loop.